# How to return all numbers in chartkick without using group_by

Tags: ruby, chartkick

I am fairly new to ruby and playing with ChartKick and not seeing any lines on the chart. I allow users to enter numbers 1-10 and I want to display all those values in a line_chart. I am returning all the values below in the loop and I want those numbers in the chart as well.

I know I am getting the data now because the colors are showing on the right for each value listed below.  I have attached a screen shot to help.  I would appreciate any help I can get.  Thanks in advance!

Here is my view

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <h3>Numbers Added</h3>
      <%= line_chart @numbers, {height: "400px", library: {hAxis: {title: "All Entered Numbers"}, vAxis: {title: "Numbers", viewWindow: {min: 0, max:10}}}} %>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>All Numbers</th>
  </tr>

  <% @numbers.each do |number| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number.value %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', number_path(number) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_number_path(number) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', number_path(number),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Add new number', new_number_path %>

</table>
```

Here is my controller

```
class NumbersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @numbers = Number.all
  end
```

Screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: i do no nothing about chartkick, but have you tried this:
<%= line_chart  @numbers.map(&:values), { ... ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, it didn't work.  The graph is empty and the colors aren't showing on the right anymore.  It also says undefined for that axis now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line chart is basically just a X-Y Coordinate System.

[image: X & Y Axis]

To Draw a Point you need an X and an Y Coordinate.
But you gave only 1 coordinate in an Array like this:

```
[1,21,44,12,55,12,9,0,78,12]
```

What you actually need is an Hash  like this:

```
{
  0 => 1,
  1 => 21,
  2 => 44,
  ...
 }
```

To achiev that you can use following code:

```
<%= line_chart Hash[(0...@numbers.size).zip @numbers.map(&:values)], 
{height: "400px", library: {hAxis: {title: "All Entered Numbers"}, 
 vAxis: {title: "Numbers", viewWindow: {min: 0, max:10}}}} %>
```

This does multiple things at once.
First it creates an Array with the numbers from 0 to the count (Exlusive the count) of your data:

```
(0...@numbers.size) =>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The next step is to collect all values from your numbers, @number is actually an array of ActiveRecord Objects, but you only want to have the values:

```
@numbers.map(&:values)
```

This function calls values on every object in @numbers and creates an Array with the results. Now we have two Arrays:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 21, 44, 12, 55, 12, 9, 0, 78, 12]
```

The .zip combines them, by taking one of each into an new Array, now we have the following:

```
[
  [0, 1], [1, 21], [2, 44], [3, 12], [4, 55], 
  [5, 12], [6, 9], [7, 0], [8, 78], [9, 12]
]
```

No we can just cast this into a hash with Hash[...] and voila we have this:

```
{
  0 => 1,
  1 => 21,
  2 => 44,
  ...
 }
```

Comment: You are amazing!  That works perfectly now.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Do you understand what was your Problem, or should i explain ?

Comment: That would be very helpful.  I am not sure how the zip is working.

Comment: @rscottbradshaw I've Updated the answer

Comment: Your explanation was great @DoktorOSwaldo.  I understand every part of the code now and exactly what it is doing.  I was close but couldn't figure out how to get the values to the x-axis.  Thank you so much for explaining that.